# A ∆ with sides 3,6,8cm. Now, a man runs around ∆ in such way that he is always at distance of 1cm from sides of∆ then how much distance will he travel

Tags: trigonometry

I don't know to proceed in this question , I am not getting what will be the man's path . How to think about that path ?

Comment: A *very* little man, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** As he runs along each side of the triangle, the path will be parallel to the side, and exactly as long as that side. As he rounds each corner, the path will be a circular arc of radius $1$ connecting the straight components. There will be three such circular components, and they will fit together exactly to form a circle of radius $1$ (draw a picture).

Comment: Yeah , thanks I got it.

Comment: So this suggests a more general result: An $\epsilon$-distant path around a convex polygon of perimeter $P$ has length $P+2\pi\epsilon$.

Comment: is it a standard result or have some proof

Comment: I am having difficulty in finding the length of arc , can you help me in that. finding θ in this will be very long and difficult

Comment: It's just what you can easily observe. It should be clear that the part parallel to the sides is of the same length (the original perimeter), and that you "hook up" the sides with circular arcs of fixed radius. The only thing is to recognize that the total external angle traversed is always $360^{\circ}$. That's probably a standard result.

Comment: The length of the arc is exactly the circumference of a circle of radius $1$ cm. Do you know the formula $C=2\pi r$? The runner only changes direction as he rounds corners. He ends up facing the same direction he originally faced as he started to run, so he turned exactly 1 revolution ($360^{\circ}$).

Comment: But I thought that it was L = r θ

Comment: Yes here $\theta=2\pi$. It must be measured in radians, not degrees.

Comment: thanks I finally got my doubt. Sorry , for disturbing you.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the man will be running parallel to the triangle's sides. The only problem arises in how he turns the corners. Here, he must stay 1cm from the vertex, so he'll turn the corners in circular arcs.